# How to use success and error in Angularjs if not using $http?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Below is my code for querying a resultset in angularjs. Below is both controller.js and services.js. However I want to get .success and .error defined in my getResult call so that I can defined different $scopes for each flow and show it on UI accordingly. I searched but everywhere I got it for $http which I am not using. As I am new to angularjs, could you please help me out with it?

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl3', ['$scope', 'PFactory', '$location', function ($scope, PFactory, $location) {

$scope.getResult = function () {
    $scope.allposts = PFactory.postmain.query();
    $location.path('/view2');
}
```

services.js is:

```
 return  {
    postmain: $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        create: {method: 'POST'}
    }),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `success` and `error` callbacks to resource actions (`query`, `create`, etc.) and get response data as callback parameter. Here is an example of doing it:

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app',['ngResource']).
  service('PFactory', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return {
      postmain: $resource('data.json', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        create: {method: 'POST'}
      })
    }
  }]).
  controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'PFactory', function($scope, PFactory) {
    PFactory.postmain.query(function success(data){
      $scope.message = 'Number of records loaded: '+data.length;
    }, function error() {
      $scope.message = 'Server Error!'
    });
  }]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/k5LgMPkU6jAteaFCn74C?p=preview

AngularJS documentation: [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)